# R: How can I Split and Trim Data Successfully

Tags: r

I've successfully split the data and removed the "," with the following code:

s = MSA_data$area_title
str_split(s, pattern = ",")

```
    Result
    [1] "Albany" " GA"
```

I need to trim this data, removing white space, however this places the comma back into the data which was initially removed.

```
          "Albany, GA"
```

How can I successfully split and trim the data so that the result is:

```
[1] "Albany" "GA"
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use `trimws` function to trim the whitespace at the beginning and end of the string.

```
Result <- trimws(Result)
```

Comment: How did I not know this function?

Answer (score 0):

We just need to use zero or more spaces (`\\s*`) (the question OP asked) and this can be done in a single step

```
strsplit(MSA_data$area_title, pattern = ",\\s*")
```

---

If we are using the `stringr`, then make use of the `str_trim`

```
library(stringr)
str_trim(str_split("Albany, GA", ",")[[1]])
#[1] "Albany" "GA"
```